# WebGL fixing texture of cells in a grid without duplicated vertices

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I am writing a web app using WebGL where I create a grid of vertices which is assembled into quads, a bit like a grid.

This is what it looks like, fully textured.

[image: sample]

It works fine, but there is a problem. The texture is the following 8x8 image with 2 arrows, one pointing left and one pointing up.

[image: texture]

At this point, you may have realized that the texture is flipped in all directions depending on the vertex.

I use the following Dart code to create the vertices. This shouldn't be too hard to follow for javascript developers though

```
    vertices = new Float32List(verts * ChunkRenderer.FLOATS_PER_VERTEX);

    for (int i = 0; i < w + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < h + 1; j++) {
            int index = (i + j * (w + 1)) * ChunkRenderer.FLOATS_PER_VERTEX;

            double x = i * 16.0;
            double z = j * 16.0;
            double y = 0.0;

            double r = rand.nextDouble();
            double g = rand.nextDouble();
            double b = rand.nextDouble();

            double u = i % 2 == 0 ? 0.0 : 1.0;
            double v = j % 2 == 0 ? 0.0 : 1.0;

            vertices.setAll(index, [
                x, y, z,
                   u, v,
                r, g, b,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

These lines in particular are responsible for setting the UV mapping

```
double u = i % 2 == 0 ? 0.0 : 1.0;
double v = j % 2 == 0 ? 0.0 : 1.0;
```

Is there a way to reuse the vertices for each triangle without messing up the textures or do I really need to duplicate vertices for each cells?

I like this current setup because I can move one vertex up for example and it will create a "spike" if you will. If each cell had their own vertices instead, I'd have to update 4 different vertices to get the same effect (excluding vertices on the edges of the grid of course)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can provide 4 pairs of (U,V) for each vertex and then decide which one use.

I don't know your render code so it's hard to provide any example.

Comment: I actually had that idea yesterday soon after posting this question but then I realized, how should the shader know which pair to use anyway?

Comment: If you draw quads one by one you can add a uniform to indicate which quad you are drawing. If you use instanced rendering you can create extra buffer with this data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most basic form of reuse would be to prepare the mesh data for one quad, and then redraw that quad with a different translation and rotation information for each draw call. This would be significantly less performant than what you're doing, because of the extra draw calls, but would also require less memory.